# Block insert/delete rows on excel

Tags: excel, vba

I made a file with the following code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
        .Protect AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _ 
        AllowInsertingRows:=False, _ 
        AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _ 
        AllowDeletingRows:=False 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Now all the excel files have the block for insert/delete no mater the extension (xlsm,xls etc) . I have restarted the PC but the problem is always there. Every new excel has blocked insert/delete rows/columns and the first sheet is protected. Any help is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: what you mean by block ?

Comment: Unless the code is somehow saved in your default workbook template, or there's something you've omitted from your question, it shouldn't cause the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Why don't you protect the worksheet and select to tick everything Insert Columns/Rows and Delete Columns/Rows. If you want to reverse this simply too for now, just change all those False values to True, save and reopen the workbook.

Comment: Most probably it changed the default template. did you try setting those properties to true?  
AllowInsertingRows:=true, _ 
AllowDeletingColumns:=true, _ 
AllowDeletingRows:=true

Comment: Hi, yes i have made it with true, run it, close open, but it just doesn't work. Its just stupid. The protect worksheet with selection of block columns/rows  insertion/delete turned on didn't work before macro.